# How to make animation on click only?

Tags: javascript, css

I made a small animation
When clicked, the animated square will change its height, but it will also animate when the window size / scale is changed. How to make it animate only when clicked, and in other cases just resize (no animation)

```js
    function myClick() {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").style.height = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + "vmin";
    }
```

```css
#myDiv {
        width: 20vmin;
        height: 20vmin;
        background: green;
        transition: height 1s ease;
    }

    #myDiv:active {
        background: blue;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
    <div id="myDiv" onclick="myClick()"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

One method is to add a class with transition and remove it after animation finished:

```js
var timer;
document.getElementById("myDiv").addEventListener("transitionend", function(e)
{
    clearTimeout(timer);
    document.getElementById("myDiv").classList.toggle("clicked", false);
}, false);

function myClick() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    document.getElementById("myDiv").classList.toggle("clicked", true);
    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.height = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + "vmin";
    timer = setTimeout(function() { //backup plan
        document.getElementById("myDiv").classList.toggle("clicked", false);
    }, 2000);
}
```

```css
#myDiv {
    width: 20vmin;
    height: 20vmin;
    background: green;
}

#myDiv:active {
    background: blue;
}
#myDiv.clicked {
    transition: height 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="myDiv" onclick="myClick()"></div>
</body>
```

Another method is to remove transition class when window is resized

```js
function myClick() {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").classList.toggle("clicked", true);
    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.height = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + "vmin";
}

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").classList.toggle("clicked", false);
});
```

```css
#myDiv {
    width: 20vmin;
    height: 20vmin;
    background: green;
}

#myDiv:active {
    background: blue;
}
#myDiv.clicked {
    transition: height 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="myDiv" onclick="myClick()"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know is the listening window resize event.

We are removing the transition effect while resizing in here;

```
const myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv")

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
myDiv.style.transition = "all 0s ease 0s"
});
```

But then you have to put the transition back when you click like this;

```
function myClick() {
if(myDiv.style.transition === "all 0s ease 0s"){
  myDiv.style.transition = "height 1s ease";
 }
    myDiv.style.height = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + "vmin";
    }
```

Comment: Question is not how to make it react on resize, it is how not to. And code presented dos not anyway.

Comment: @ikiK It is reacting on window resize because it has transition property, so while resizing it's gonna behave according to that transition. Go open it on full page and downsize your window you are gonna see the effect, he doesn't want that. You didn't get the question I suppose.

Comment: I did check it, nothing happens.

Comment: it has vmin unit so it'll get smaller while going on phone size, something must happen.

Comment: Actually it does yes, and 5 min has passed and I can not remove down-vote. If you edit the answer I can. Please do so.

Comment: It was reacting only when I had fiddle in full screen, not while just activating it normally. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way.  It's a bit crude but it works.  The div only has an `animate` class while the animation is taking place, using a timer.  I made the timer longer than necessary and it turns yellow to make clear what's happening.  I'm not sure if it can be done without a timer kludge.

```js
    let animateTimeout;
    function myClick() {
        let myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
        myDiv.style.height = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + "vmin";
        myDiv.classList.add("animate");
        clearTimeout(animateTimeout);
        animateTimeout = setTimeout(() => myDiv.classList.remove("animate"), 1500);
    }
```

```css
    #myDiv {
        width: 20vmin;
        height: 20vmin;
        background: green;
    }
    #myDiv.animate {
        background: yellow;
        transition: height 1s ease;
    }

    #myDiv:active {
        background: blue;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
    <div id="myDiv" onclick="myClick()"></div>
</body>
</html>
```